# Solr indexing fails over media_black_point

Tags: solr

In front i want to say that i dont have much experience with Solr.

Problem we are facing, we only want to index content of files and not want to add dynamic fields, is this possible and if so how?

Problem 2: If Problem one is a No, how would we exclude media_black_point, 
media_white_point with indexing?

Error code where Solr trips:

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":149},"error":{"metadata":["error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException","root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],"msg":"incompatible dimension (2) and values (313/1000 329/1000).  Only 0 values specified","code":400}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic Fields and schemaless mode are both there to catch fields you did not declare explicitly. If neither are used, the assumption is that every field you send to Solr (including output from extract handler that generates a Solr document internally) needs to be explicitly mapped. This helps to avoid spelling errors and other unexpected edge-cases.

If you want to ignore all the fields you did not define explicitly, you can use dynamic field with stored/indexed/docValues all set to false. Solr ships with [one example](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/server/solr/configsets/basic_configs/conf/managed-schema#L178) out of the box, you just need to uncomment it.

The other option is to ignore specific fields. You can do that by defining a custom [UpdateRequestProcessor chain](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Update+Request+Processors) (or individual URP in the latest Solr) and using [IgnoreFieldUpdateProcessorFactory](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/solr/update/processor/IgnoreFieldUpdateProcessorFactory.html) with your specific field name or a name pattern.